# Download and play videos (simultaneously) in Recycler View android

Tags: android, download, video-streaming, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I want to develop recyclerview in which I have multiple video URL. I want to download all the videos as well as they should play simultaneously on the list.

**is it possible to download and play at the same time in recycler view???**

i have read one tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429#.8vdic0sas). I want to develop the same list like this. but videos should get download and play simultaneously.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to stream the video's instead of downloading?

Comment: its just because ... if the video is already downloaded i can give the sd card path rather that stream it again again...

Comment: that's what a cache is for

Comment: How could download and play works simultaneously, either you have to complete the download and play the video / or / to stream live.

Comment: so its not feasible....  right ? HariRam

Comment: Logically it will not possible. You have to choose live Streaming.

Comment: its possible.. download video in chucks like 4mb files. play which how many chunks downloaded. Play will be little late.

Comment: thanks sush ... probally its great solution. i'm little new to android. can you pls elaborate something for this approach or it would be much better if it is possible for you to give some reference links.